# DECLARE & SET variables up top, then WHERE LIKE filter?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been declaring variables up top for long and complicated SQLs, but looking for advice on how to make it more flexible. How can I use LIKE filters?

```
declare street_names array <string>;
declare house_num array <string>;

SET street_names = array['Elm Street','Maple Street'];
SET house_num = array['3305','1234','4444'];

SELECT *
FROM streetnamestable
WHERE 1=1
and Street in UNNEST(street_names)
and Address in UNNEST(house_num)
;
```

How can I make this more flexible, to allow for streen_names like '%ave%' for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`REGEXP_CONTAINS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains) at the where clause to make this more flexible when you add the filters.

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(Street,'ave')
```

The full query should look like this:

```
declare street_names array <string>;
declare house_num array <string>;
 
SET street_names = array['Elm Street','Maple Street'];
SET house_num = array['3305','1234','4444'];
 
SELECT *
FROM `dataset.table`
WHERE 1=1
and street in UNNEST(street_names) OR REGEXP_CONTAINS(Street,'ave') 
and Address in UNNEST(house_num)
```

The problem using this is that this cannot be used in an array, so maybe it helps you with being more flexible; but you would need to do many `REGEXP_CONTAINS` if you want to be flexible with all the `street_names` that you want to use.

Comment: so no way to parameterize and declare a wildcard term up top to then be referenced in a LIKE clause later?

Comment: @surfer349 unfortunately, there is no way to do this in a wildcard using Bigquery.

Comment: @surfer349 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.